# java fx 2 - sort table with paging

Tags: sorting, pagination, javafx-2, tableview

I have a table with Pagination. When a user click a column to apply sorting, only the current page is getting sorted. However, I need to apply the sort on the db level. I need to apply custom sort functionality, so when a user clicks the header I go to the db with 'SORT BY.. ASC/DESC' clause.

What is the best way of doing it? How can I receive sort events (when user click the column header)?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX 8, you can provide custom sorting via the sortPolicy property.

In JavaFX 2.2, you don't have the option to do this. You can get a notification of when a sort is performed: call getSortOrder() on the table; this returns an ObservableList of TableColumns representing which column(s) are used for the sort order. You can register a listener with this list, which will get notified when the sort order changes. As far as I know, though, there is no way to change the default sort behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I get notification of when a sort is perform?

Comment: As I stated in the answer: call getSortOrder() and register a listener with the list that is returned.